# Is this word order correct?

Tags: meaning, sentence-construction, word-order

I have a problem with such a sentence:

> Today is used not only lime, soda ash and sodium sulfide but also trithiocarbonates.

I am not certain whether all elements needed are included.

Will the following version be ok?

> Today, it is used not only lime, soda ash and sodium sulfide but also trithiocarbonates.

Maybe this version is better?

> Today, there is used not only lime, soda ash and sodium sulfide but also trithiocarbonates.

From comments: But the main thing is that I want this sentence to be like a suggestion. I want to express that currently there are more widely used substances (except from these mentioned) for this specific purpose.

I am ready to see your suggestions.

Comment: Are you talking about the compounds used on this specific day, or just in this general current time period (used would be specific to today, use would be for current times)

Comment: By Today I mean Currently

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> Today is used not only lime, soda ash and sodium sulphide but also trithiocarbonates

or

> Today, it is used not only lime, soda ash and sodium sulphide but also trithiocarbonates.

---

The word order in the list is fine but in both cases the sentence is incorrect. Because "***is***" is incorrect.

**Today *we used*** or he, she, I, they or a "**name**"... used, not only lime........

Today, "**the process**" used not only lime, soda ash and sodium sulphide but also trithiocarbonates.

> **is** UK ​ he/she/it form of be

---

In the sentence **Today, it is used not only lime**.... "**it**" is is not correct **it** refers to something previously known. Here in this sentence it makes no sense.

> This is your room - it is rather small, I'm afraid.

This is your room - it (the room) is rather small, I'm afraid.

> **it pronoun** (THING) used as the subject of a verb, or the object of a verb or preposition, to refer to a thing, animal, situation, or idea that has already been mentioned:

[All references Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/it)

---

**Update**

But the main thing is that I want this sentence to be **like a suggestion**. I want to express that currently there are more widely used substances (except from these mentioned) for this specific purpose.

**Today, let's use not only lime, soda ash and sodium sulphide but also trithiocarbonates**

Comment: @I am aware that be might "be" used in a spoken version of this sentence in a few colloquial dialects

Comment: Thank you Brad! But what if I want to have this sentence in passive (is used) to underline general usage of the following substances, continuously having Today in the first place? Is it possible?

Comment: or '*Today, **we use(d)** not only lime, soda ash and sodium sulphide but also trithiocarbonates*' - with the (d) if they mean which compounds were used specifically this day, **without (d) if comparing the current general time period to a previous time period where the compounds used were different.**

Comment: When it comes to Today I had Currently in mind. Please, could you tell me if the version with there is ok?

Comment: @Piotr Pocheć; Actually it makes no sense Smock's suggestion is correct but not in this sentence. ................but also bicarbonates makes it specific to this day/batch. You would need to adjust the sentence to ........Today, we (will) use  lime, soda ash, sodium sulphide and trithiocarbonates'

Comment: So the version "Today, we use not only lime...but also trithiocarbonates." underlines the general usage of these substances? I am not a native and I find it difficult to work out.

Comment: Sorry but because you are not a native it is also hard for me to find out what you want. The use of ...".not only"........."but also.... trithiocarbonates" indicates an exception to the normal. The use of.... "and trithiocarbonates"  just moves it into the list and indicates NO exception to the normal.

Comment: Thank you, I see. I want to say that there not only the following substances to make use of but also trithiocarbonates, for example, to improve a conduct of a  experiment. But the main thing is that I want this sentence to be like a suggestion. I want to express that currently there are more widely used substances (except from these mentioned) for this specific purpose. Anyway, thank you for help.

Comment: Today, let's use not only lime, soda ash and sodium sulphide but also trithiocarbonates...........let verb (SUGGEST) let's (also formal let us),,,, used to express a suggestion or request that includes you and the other person or people:

Let's go out to dinner.